# Aplicação Windows Server 2012 com domínio Locaweb

Tags: dns

Tenho um servidor do Google Cloud Windows Server 2012, mas não entendo muito de infra. Como faço para apontar um domínio que tenho na Locaweb para a minha aplicação rodando no IIS?
No site da locaweb pede que eu configure o DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa de somente dois itens:

- Criar uma entrada DNS no [Painel de Controle da LocaWeb](http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Acessando_o_Gerenciador_de_DNS);
- Criar um BIND no IIS com este endereço.

Depois de criar a entrada no seu DNS, você deve selecionar o seu site na tela de configuração no IIS, clicar sobre "associações" (binds) adicionar a sua e aguardar somente o tempo de propagação do DNS que você criou. O tempo de propagação varia de servidor para servidor.

Na Locaweb, criar o subdomínio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após o acerto, é bom se certificar que está tudo certo com a configuração, fazendo uma consulta direta ao servidor de DNS. Para fazer isso você pode executar pela linha de comando o [nslookup](http://www.tutoriaisti.com.br/sistemas-operacionais/windows/comandos-redes/). Existem sites com [ferramentas online](http://www.webdnstools.com/dnstools/dns-lookup) que também podem ajudar muito nesta consulta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No IIS, a edição é bem simples:

- **Tipo:** Protocolo do Site. Se usar https, precisará selecionar um certificado SSL instalado no servidor.
- **Nome do Host:** O endereço criado no DNS
- **Porta:** Porta usada na comunicação.
- **IP:** Ou você coloca o * que representa qualquer endereço de entrada ou seleciona o IP interno da interface que será responsável por atender as requisições

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Entrada de dns no portal da locaweb?

Comment: Isso. No painel de controle você tem uma edição avançada que exibe sua tabela de DNS. Você precisa criar uma, ou do tipo A ou do tipo CNAME. [Dê uma olhada nesta ajuda](http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Como_criar,_editar_ou_excluir_entradas_no_DNS). O acesso ao painel de controle é por [aqui](http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Acessando_o_Gerenciador_de_DNS).

Comment: Criei uma tipo A apontando pro IP do meu servidor. Onde eu obtenho o dns com o nome do host? To com dúvida em como configurar isso na locaweb.

Comment: Na locaweb é só fazer a alteração no DNS. Essa entrada já enviará o endereço para seu IP. Agora precisa alterar o IIS conforme explicado para que ele reconheça o host de entrada e transfira para o serviço correto.

Comment: O tipo A aceita apenas IP. Onde eu obtenho o host? (desculpe minha dificuldade em entender)

Comment: A entrada DNS é: subdomínio (www, app, etc), um tipo (A, CNAME, etc), um IP (ex.:177.21.16.40) e um tempo de refresh (TTL). O seu domínio já está na locaweb. Você precisa criar um sub-domínio que faça a correlação do host com o IP.

Comment: No seu caso, como seu servidor não está dentro da Locaweb, indico que você crie um do tipo CNAME.

Comment: Obrigado mesmo!